# How to fix errors that involve Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to make a Facebook marketplace scraper. I am using Microsoft Edge and every time I run the code, it gives me a few errors that I do not know how to fix. This is all I have so far, and it is supposed to print the year of a car and the name of it.

Ex: 2009 Honda Accord

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


s=Service('C:\\Users\\CPM\\Downloads\\edgedriver_win64 (3) msedgedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)

url = 'https://www.facebook.com'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep((20))

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/category/vehicles?minPrice=0&maxPrice=5000&maxMileage=150000&minMileage=0&sortBy=creation_time_descend&topLevelVehicleType=car_truck&exact=false'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

elements = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz x1heor9g x1lku1pv')


for ele in elements:
    print(ele.get_attribute('title'))
```

I've tried different class names and fixed the function names but I still get these errors,

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63009/devtools/browser/99d7d32b-bcb8-49d3-bce9-a737cb9b9fef
[12308:2292:1127/164624.744:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(450)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string: 

[12308:2292:1127/164646.905:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\CPM\Downloads\rubiks_cube-master\rubiks_cube-master\new folder\improvedscraper.py", line 19, in <module>
    elements = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz x1heor9g x1lku1pv')
  File "C:\Users\CPM\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 861, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\CPM\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\CPM\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz x1heor9g x1lku1pv"}
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=107.0.1418.56)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperties::SetProperty [0x00007FF696738532+9986]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF6966D5D62+1445202]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6962BFC8C+654476]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6963036C2+931522]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF696303B10+932624]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF69633FC17+1178647]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF696323BDF+1063903]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6962F5FF4+876532]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF69633CF70+1167216]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6963239B3+1063347]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6962F506A+872554]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6962F402E+868398]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6962F570F+874255]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF696596108+135416]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF6965802CF+45759]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF69658374C+59196]
        Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6963CB1F4+1749492]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF6966DB65A+1467978]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF6966DFEF4+1486564]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF6966E004D+1486909]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF6966E7E0B+1519099]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFC227F74B4+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFC236626A1+33]
```

Answer (score 0):

It tells you what the error is:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":".x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y
> xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr
> x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq
> x1a2a7pz x1heor9g x1lku1pv"}

Make sure you're searching for elements that actually exist.

Comment: I directly copied and pasted that element from facebook marketplace though...

Comment: It's dynamically generated, it had a different value for the Selenium session.

Comment: So, I'm guessing this way of screen scraping is impossible due to the fact that Facebook makes sure you can't use one due to the aria-hidden="true" function.

Comment: Hello and good day dear Deo and DMcC - many thanks for the question - and this great thread:   well i found out that we can scrape fb eg: see here: https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/
question: well can i scrape fb pages for a special key category - eg. 
female and  single  - is this possible!?